# Angularjs http call and saving received data to the controller instance

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope, $http, nonService){
    this.someVar = 'Hello World';

    $http.post('funcsPHP/2.0/getConditionProductService.php', 
        { 'product' : angular.toJson(this.productObj) }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.saveData = data; // works fine
            this.saveData = data // 'this' doesnt refer to the controller 'sampleCtrl' anymore, but to the $http instance, right ?
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            // log error
    });
});
```

I am aware that I am able to save data to the $scope, but I would like to know how I would be able to save data to a controller variable, such as 'this.someVar'. Do I have to inject an instance of my controller into the $http ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways.

The easiest is to just assign a variable to point to the `this` value in your controller. The most common names are `_this`, `self`, and `that`.

So you get:

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope, $http, nonService){
    this.someVar = 'Hello World';
    var self = this;

    $http.post('funcsPHP/2.0/getConditionProductService.php', 
        { 'product' : angular.toJson(this.productObj) }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.saveData = data;
            self.saveData = data;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            // log error
        });
});
```

The other way is to use [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for your success handler to set `this` correctly inside it.

That would give you:

```
app.controller('sampleCtrl', function($scope, $http, nonService){
    this.someVar = 'Hello World';

    $http.post('funcsPHP/2.0/getConditionProductService.php', 
        { 'product' : angular.toJson(this.productObj) }).
        success((function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.saveData = data;
            this.saveData = data;
        }).bind(this))
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            // log error
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use "Controller As" way of accessing your controllers instance variables:

```
 <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl as ctrl">
      {{ctrl.someVar}}
 </div>
```

Comment: The OP was not asking how to refer to the controller instance variable in the markup, they were asking how to add a property to the controller instance inside an async callback in the controller.